# An inequality involving a normal integral

Tags: analysis, inequality, probability-distributions

The following inequality "seems" true by simulation, but an analytic justification/disproof doesn't seem straightforward. The integral part does not admit a closed-form expression in general, although one can show that the LHS and RHS are equal when $\theta=0$. Viewing the inequality as a function of $\theta$ and taking derivative does not seem useful. So I was wondering if there is any technique or counterexample that can help. Any hints/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

For all $\theta<0$ and each $a\geqslant 0$, we have
$$\Phi(\theta)-\Phi(\theta-a)>\int_{-a}^a \Phi(x+\theta)\phi(x-\theta)dx,$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ denote the standard normal cdf and pdf, respectively.

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to $a$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't find it worth typing it as a more detailed answer ;-)

Comment: @AnneBauval Fair enough~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
I(\theta, a) = \Phi(\theta) - \Phi(\theta-a) - \int_{-a}^a \Phi(x+\theta)\phi(x-\theta)dx
$$
You want to show that $I(\theta, a)>0$ $\forall a\ge 0$.

In the case where $a=0$:  $I(\theta, 0) = \Phi(\theta) - \Phi(\theta) - 0 \equiv 0$.

Note that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left( \int_{-a}^a f(x)dx \right) = f(-a)+f(a)
$$

In the case where $a > 0$, differentiate $I(\theta, a)$ with respect to $a$:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}I(\theta, a) = \phi(\theta-a) - \Phi(-a+\theta)\phi(-a-\theta) - \Phi(a+\theta)\phi(a-\theta) \\
= \phi(\theta-a) - \Phi(\theta-a)\phi(-\theta-a) - \Phi(\theta+a)\phi(\theta-a) \\
= (1-\Phi(\theta+a))\phi(\theta-a) - \Phi(\theta - a)\phi(-\theta-a)
$$

We must show that
$$
(1-\Phi(\theta+a))\phi(\theta-a) - \Phi(\theta - a)\phi(-\theta-a) \ge 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow 
\frac{1-\Phi(\theta+a)}{\phi(-\theta-a)} \ge \frac{\Phi(\theta - a)}{\phi(\theta-a)} \\
\Leftrightarrow
\frac{\Phi(-\theta-a)}{\phi(-\theta-a)} \ge \frac{\Phi(\theta - a)}{\phi(\theta-a)}
$$

(We have applied the identities $\phi(-x) \equiv \phi(x)$ and $\Phi(-x) \equiv 1-\Phi(x)$ in several places.)

The LHS and RHS of the above inequality are mirror images of each other about the y-axis. Since $G(\theta) := {\Phi(\theta-a)} / {\phi(\theta-a)}$ is a positive, increasing function, the LHS is indeed greater than the RHS when $\theta\le 0$, with equality iff $\theta=0$.